# Javac installed but not working

Tags: java, javac

I want to compile my first java code but it is showing the following for javac :

```
The program 'javac' can be found in the following packages:

 * default-jdk
 * ecj
 * gcj-4.6-jdk
 * gcj-4.7-jdk
 * openjdk-7-jdk
 * openjdk-6-jdk
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

I installed openjdk but still it is showing the same thing as above.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

openjdk-7-jre is already the newest version.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java JRE will not include the command `javac` because it is the Java Runtime Environment.

You require a Java JDK -- Java Development Kit.  Install `openjdk-7-jdk` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The JRE (Java Runtime Environment) is not a [JDK (Java Developers Kit)](http://java.com/en/download/faq/develop.xml). You need a JDK for `javac`.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Answer (score 1):

You have installed jre but to use javac you must install jdk.

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

install jdk

And then try again